# enableWhiteboard() function getting a response with SERVICE_EXCEPTION error in Circuit SDK

Tags: javascript, circuit-sdk

I am trying to enable Whiteboard using **Circuit SDK** by running **enableWhiteboard(callId, viewbox)**, where **callId** is the ID of the current call and **viewbox** an object containing the device's screen *width* and *height*. When I call it, the response code is "SERVICE_EXCEPTION" and errorCode is "UNEXPECTED_ERROR", with info being "General Client API service exception: null".

The log captured using Chrome is linked below:

[Circuit SDK - enableWhiteboard() log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjaHv.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? That exception is turning out to be hard to debug, but I think I may be missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are working on improving these errors.

Whiteboarding still requires special permissions that only the system admin can set. Please let me know the user(s) or bots you'd like to have the permission assigned.